# PowerShell script to count members of multiple groups without duplicates

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I need to write a PowerShell script that will count the users in 4 groups:
group1
group2
group3
group4

The script needs to skip duplicates if a user is in multiple groups.

Previously I was using the following script to count users in each group separately, but it is including duplicates and I need the accurate count of users from all groups.

```
$ADInfo = Get-ADGroup -Identity '<groupname>' -Properties Members
$ADInfo.Members |Where-Object {(Get-ADUser $_ -Properties extensionAttribute4).extensionAttribute4 -eq 'o365_facstaff'} |Select -Unique | Measure-Object
```

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust this to send a collection down the pipeline. Something like the below should work:

```
$Groups = 'Group1','Group2','Group3','Group4'

$Groups |
Get-ADGroup -Properties Member |
Where-Object {(Get-ADUser $_ -Properties extensionAttribute4).extensionAttribute4 -eq 'o365_facstaff'} |
Select-Object -Unique |
Measure-Object
```

However, I would probably go about it a little different:

```
$Groups = 'Group1','Group2','Group3','Group4'

$Groups | 
Get-ADGroupMember |
Where-Object{ $_.objectCLass -eq 'user'} |
Get-ADUser -Properties extensionAttribute4 |
Where-Object{ $_.extensionAttribute4 -eq 'o365_facstaff' } |
Select-Object -Unique | 
Measure-Object
```

Note: In your original code the `Get-ADUser` command might error if you send it a group since groups can be members of other groups.  That's why there's an extra `Where{}` clause in the above example to only looking for objectClass 'user'.

If you care to mess with the group Distinguished Names you could also try using an LDAP filter:

```
$Groups = @(
    'Group1_DN'
    'Group2_DN'
    'Group3_DN'
    'Group4_DN'
)

$LDAPFilter = "(&(extensionAttribute4=o365_facstaff)(|(memberOf={0})(memberOf={1})(memberOf={2})(memberOf={3})))" -f $Groups

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $LDAPFilter |
Select-Object -Unique |
Measure-Object
```

This will return all users where extensionAttribute4 is 'o365_facstaff' that are members of any 4 groups.  Then it will run through `Select -Unique` & `Measure-Object` as before.

Note: Performance probably isn't a big factor in this case.  However, it's always a best practice to move filtering left in the command as opposed to post filtering with a `Where{}` clause or other secondary processing.  In this case, leveraging the cmdlet's built-in filtering parameters.